# Android Instrumentation Test : ListView content not loading

Tags: android, listview, testing, junit, android-cursorloader

I am trying to code test classes for my android project, and I am encountering some issues with filling listviews.

My activity perform a request on the application DB, using values provided with Intents :

```
    final String[] projection = {
             ...
            };

    final String[] selectionArgs={
            String.valueOf(intent_param_1),
            String.valueOf(intent_param_2)
    };
    final String selection = //.... ;

    vAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.da_row, null, from, to,0);

    mListView = new LoaderUtils(vAdapter, projection, selection, selectionArgs, this, uri, null).populateListView(mListView);
```

The LoaderUtils class implements LoaderCallbacks, and the method populateListView uses a CursorLoader to load DB data to the adapter and bind it to my ListView.
It works fine when running my application, but when I'm trying to implement the test cases I'm running into some problems.

```
@Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("intent_param_1", 1);
    i.putExtra("intent_param_2", 1);
    setActivityIntent(i);

    mActivity = getActivity();
    listeActivites = (ListView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = (CustomCursorAdapter) listeActivites.getAdapter();
  }

public void testInit(){
    Cursor c = adapter.getCursor();
            //...
    }
```

When I perform my testInit, the Cursor returned by the adapter is empty while it is not when I run my application "for real" with the emulator.

The problem might be that my Intent is badly initialized, or that test cases doesn't allow to work with Cursor Loaders? So if anyone could point what I am doing wrong, it would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that CursorLoader has not yet finished. If you add a sleep of like one second (not the right way), than it will work.

I am currently as well searching on how to test activities with CursorLoaders best. Since I do not want to add sleep code... There must be a better way.

Currently thinking of adding a listener for which I can wait in the tests...